# Why do planets not radiate EM waves in their orbits?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, estimation

Despite being overall near-netural, I would expect the individual electrons and proton to radiate long EM waves as we accelerate around the Sun or rotate around our poles. Is the acceleration so small that the radiated energy is miniscule?

Or is it that somehow the macroscopic neutrality prevent radiation? If this is so, what mechanism causes single electrons or nuclei to fail to radiate?

Comment: The acceleration is too small.

Comment: See, now you given me my favorite soap box: in all the quantitative science *scale* matters. No one talks about such radiations, not because it doesn't happen but because the expected size of the effect is so vanishingly small that there isn't a hope of even detecting it. This is the kind of problem for which a physicist would first and foremost do a back-of-the-envelope estimate. Then they'd drop the whole thing as a non-issue.

Comment: Moving in space around a massive body do you feel a acceleration? Of course not and such a movement Is called a geodesic trajectory. Since the attribute acceleration is not applicable to the movement on geodesic paths it is arbitrary emit a particle EM radiation or not. BUT if it emit the particle has to move on a spiral path towards the massive body because it looses energy. What predicted Einsteins GR theory, is the room more bended near massive bodies than Newtons classical theory? If yes this can be an **indication** that a particle indeed emit EM radiation on geodesic paths

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The power radiated by a charged particle moving at non relativistic speeds, whose acceleration is $a$ and charge is $q$, is given by the [Larmor Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) 
$$P =\frac{2q^2a^2K}{3c^3}.$$
The product above is nowhere near $c^3$ for planetary motion and hence the radiation emitted is negligibly small.

Comment: But how to deal with the fact that on geodesic paths the acceleration is zero?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Acceleration wrt what?

Comment: @Ali Caglayan Do you feel an acceleration if you are on a geodesic path?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Yes, you can.

Comment: @Jimmy360 I can also feel an acceleration. Even in space but in this case only if I use a rocket drive. If I'm free falling there is no acceleration.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I guess you don't even have to deal with this. If we ever get large enough numerator in the Larmor formula, only then we would need to even consider possibility of radiation. But since with given parameters even SR doesn't predict detectable EM radiation, why use the more complicated theory of GR just to confirm that there's no radiation?

Comment: @Ruslan you don't get the point. Planets in their orbits follow geodesic paths. There isn't any acceleration and by this there isn't any radiation induced by (no) acceleration. Larmor formula holds for non inertial system.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/General-Relativity-If-an-object-is-in-inertial-motion-following-a-geodesic-is-it-accelerating.      See this link. There also exist frames with respect to which the planets accelerate. The larmor formula is valid in those frames, and the answer is also thus valid.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler this begins to make sense only once you incorporate GR into discussion. But even if we speak of typical accelerations of planets in the framework of SR, they still radiate almost nothing. That was my point.

Comment: @Lelouch your point is that IF the planet from a different reference frame seems to be under acceleration THEN it will radiate. Radiation means lose of thermic or kinetic or potential or ... energy. Being on the surface of a planet (not taking in account the planets rotation around his own axis) nothing accelerates due to the orbital motion along a geodesic path and by this energy is not radiated. This inconsistency you should solve, does it radiate or does it not. Or in both cases energy gets lost or not at all. The last is right, moving on gedesics nothing radiates.